# moving/floating 2 lists out of 3 to the right but keep the markup order

Tags: css, html, css-float, html-lists

i have three lists that are inline-block.
the last two i want to move them to the right of the screen but keep their markup order
i float them with and without clearfix

**problem is that i can't keep their markup order, as the third list appears before the second.**

what am i doing wrong? :/

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block; 
}

ul:nth-child(2),
ul:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
  float: right
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `float:right` will change the flow to start from the right so the result you got is logical (the first element in the DOM will be the first one on the right).

Instead of this you can use left floating with the first one and adjust `text-align` to move the other ones:

```css
body {
  text-align:right;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block; 
}

ul:nth-child(2),
ul:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
ul:nth-child(1) {
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

And for a more cleaner and modern way you can use flexbox:

```css
body {
  display:flex;
}

ul:nth-child(2),
ul:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
ul:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```